# Run a loop on background in Android

Tags: android, loops, background-process

I have a function that reads the content of the Android clipboard every two seconds and communicates all changes with a remote server.

This works fine in the app is opened. But I need to be able to continue to log the clipboard changes after the app has been closed.

So I tried an `IntentService` but it doesn't appreciate long loops.

How can I run my infinite loop in the background?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IntentService` should be used to process single "request", from another application component, at time.

Use [started service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#CreatingStartedService) which should be more suitable for problem you describe. Started service runs until you manually stops it or until system gets out of resources and kill whole process.

Use `START_STICKY` as return from `onStartCommand()` method to automatically start it again when system kills it.

If you also start it in `BroadcastReceiver` with `ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED` action service will be started after device boot.

Answer (score 2):

> I have a function that reads the content of the Android clipboard every two seconds and communicates all changes with a remote server.

Polling? You are doing it **VERY** wrong. You should use [OnPrimaryClipChangedListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ClipboardManager.OnPrimaryClipChangedListener.html) instead.

**EDIT**

> communicates all changes with a remote server.

I just realised you are basically doing some bad things there and I am bit sceptical believing your users aware you literaly spying on them? Is your app in Google Play if so what's your app package id?

Comment: Not yet, but it will be in Google Play. I understand your concern, but the remote server is on the users local network. It will allow a shared clipboard between phone and computer. No danger ;)

Comment: I upvoted your answer because it was very helpful, but it doesn't really answer my question, so the accepted answer is kycera's. Thanks for pointing out the existence of `OnPrimaryClipChangedListener`

Answer (score 0):

Implement a `Service` and make it sticky by returning `START_STICKY` in `onStartCommand` (see [Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html)):

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    // We want this service to continue running until it is explicitly
    // stopped, so return sticky.
    return START_STICKY;
}
```